# Using variable/constant outside of do{}catch{} - swift2

Tags: swift, try-catch

So on a button press I'm creating splitLat: [Double] from a throwing function called splitLatitude that takes currentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D?. I then want to use splitLat as a Label (its going to be used for other things as well but this serves the example)

```
@IBAction func ButtonPress() {
      let splitLat = try self.splitLatitude(self.currentLocation)
      LatSplitLabel.text = "\(splitLat)"
}
```

this gets a error "Errors thrown from here are not handled"

I resolve this by putting it in a do catch block

```
    do{
        let splitLat = try self.splitLatitude(self.currentLocation)
    } catch {
        print("error") //Example - Fix
    }
```

but the when i try to set the label later on splitLat is an "unresolved identifier"

New to swift and programming in general, am i missing something basic/ do i have a mis understanding? is there a way i can use the constant from the do {} statement outside of the do statement. Tried return but that is reserved for functions.

Really appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options (I'll assume that `splitLat` is `String` type)

```
do{
    let splitLat = try self.splitLatitude(self.currentLocation)
    //do rest of the code here
} catch {
    print("error") //Example - Fix
}
```

second option, predeclare the variable

```
let splitLat : String? //you can late init let vars from swift 1.2
do{
    splitLat = try self.splitLatitude(self.currentLocation)
} catch {
    print("error") //Example - Fix
}
//Here splitLat is recognized
```

Now, some explanation of your problem.
in `Swift` (and many other languages) variables are only defined inside the scope they are defined

scope is defined between these brackets `{/* scope code */ }`

```
{
    var x : Int

    {
        //Here x is defined, it is inside the parent scope
        var y : Int
    }
    //Here Y is not defined, it is outside it's scope
}
//here X is outside the scope, undefined
```

Comment: Thank you! should have been able to figure this out. Had figured option one but it wouldn't work for my purposes, but option 2 is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A 3rd option is to use a closure:

```
 let splitLat:String = { 
     do {
         return try self.splitLatitude(self.currentLocation)
     }
     catch {
         print("error") //Example - Fix
         return ""
     }
 }()
 LatSplitLabel.text = "\(splitLat)"
```

Comment: Clever! Never thought of doing it this way but I like it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping error if you want to succeed execution after the do/catch block. You must declare the variable outside of this do/catch scope in order to utilize it after the do/catch execution.

Try this:

```
var splitLat: <initialType> = <initialValue>
do {
    let splitLat = try self.splitLatitude(self.currentLocation)
} catch {
    print("error")
}

print(splitLat)
```

Here is a concocted example that runs in a Swift 2.2 playground:

```
enum Errors: ErrorType {
    case SomeBadError
}

func getResult(param: String) throws -> Bool {
    if param == "" {
        throw Errors.SomeBadError
    }
    return true
}

var result = false
do {
   result = try getResult("it")
} catch {
   print("Some error")
}

print(result)
```